# Remove Broken Plugin From Nose

Tags: python, plugins, uninstallation, nose

I tried installing a plugin for nose called html-output. I used the command

```
pip install .
```

in the directory where the setup.py file exists. It *seemed* to work ok but now when running `nosetests` I am getting the following:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/nose/plugins/manager.py:395: RuntimeWarning: Unable to load plugin html-output = htmloutput.htmloutput:HtmlOutput: No module named 'version'
  RuntimeWarning)
```

I just want to get rid of it. I've tried

```
pip uninstall .
```

But that didn't work. I even tried removing nose and reinstalling it, but I am still getting the warning. Not sure what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the package by it's name:

```
pip uninstall nosehtmloutput
```

(assuming you are using [`nose-html-output`](https://github.com/cboylan/nose-html-output) package)

Comment: Thanks, that took care of it.